# How to fix babel-polyfill error? Can't find in my code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I have a simple page with a button and a textbox, where I input a sql query, that sends data to a php file that returns the query result on the page.

Here are my codes:

```
   <div class="row larger-font">

   <div class="container">
     <p><strong> Some text goes here </strong></p>
   <div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="simpleButton">
                            <button  type="button"   class="btn btn-primary">Execute!</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sampleInput" name="sql">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div id="result">  </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
          <script>
          $('#simpleButton').click(function(e) {
          var val1 = $('#sampleInput').val();
          $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'mahsql',
          data: { sampleInput: val1 },
          success: function(response) {
          $('#result').html(response);
          }
          });
          });
          </script>
```

The weird part is, I get my results on the page, no problem; however, I get this pop up error saying only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed. I cannot understand this. I am not using anything babel. Is there a way to suppress that error from here? I am confused because I can see the result, but I  still get this annoying pop up error.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE: Here's mahsql.php:

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', 'hostname/db_svc');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
$query = $_POST['sampleInput'];
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES)     : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

Following the comments, I pushed F12 on chrome looked at the Chrome tab and I see this javascript code under my .php file with the html, that's called newtestingm.php.

This is the extra bit of code that's throwing the error:

```
<div id="preloader"></div><script type="text/javascript">
var isLoggedIn=false;
var preload=[];
var isAdmin=false;

</script><script type="text/javascript">

</script><script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)    {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new     Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)    [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-53997625-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');


</script>
<script src="http://servername:1338/webpack-dev-server.js"></script><script    crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://servername:1338/all.8a98aeb6b75576ce1df6.js">    </script><script crossorigin="anonymous"     src="http://servername:1338/newtestingm.8a98aeb6b75576ce1df6.js"></script></body>    </html>
```

What is this??? It's not part of my php file.

Answer (score 1):

The resource at `mahsql` is returning html with an embedded script tag. You are unconditionally injecting this html into your page and executing it. This is extremely unwise.

As you have not included all of your html it is difficult to determine the exact cause of the error. Basically, a script which is only intended to be executed a single time is being executed multiple times.

Based on the updates and comments it appears that your server is appending markup containing google analytics, a script requesting Webpack's development server, and also setting some global variables. Webpack is likely what is requesting Babel.

My advice is to take a step back and examine all of the tools you are using as this should not be happening without your knowledge. Perhaps you are using a combination of server and client side frameworks, starter kits, and templates that are generating code you are unaware of. The results of this are hard to predict and reason about without having an in depth knowledge of your full stack.

I don't have good knowledge of the frameworks you are using, and I rarely write PHP, but the general problem is that you are not aware of the breadth of code being executed. There is clearly a fairly complex stack in play that is making assumptions. For example it seems to be assuming that you have a Webpack bundle with a name corresponding to your html page being served from the same location. If that is not the case you will receive errors. But it is just one example of a large number of assumptions.

Comment: This is just a test page, nothing production so security isn't priority atm. I wanted to test the functionality of POST using ajax to the mahsql php file. This is all the html that you see here though. I'll update the mahsql.php file.

Comment: Look at the network tab in your browser tools and see what is being requested and what is being returned. Something is requesting a script and that script is being downloaded and executed.

Comment: Okay, I did that. I am seeing something weird. So the php file is called newtestingm.php, the one with the bootstrap html. Now in this network tab when I push F12 on chrome, I see a .js file called newtestingm(bunch of gibberish).js showing a 404 not found error. And when I open this I see some extra code under my newtestingm.php code:

Comment: Actually, the server comprises of many many pages and details; it's a whole tool basically. I was trying to make a simple page on one of the folders and call a simple php file locally without any routing, completely filled with variables from my side. It runs the query, and returns the results fine. But other two colleagues of mine worked on this tool for over 3 years, so it may be that they included something I'm unaware of?

Comment: So there is a framework in place that is processing requests and responses and appending content. If you remove the `$.ajax` call do you receive an error? What is downloaded? Start with something even simpler.

Comment: What would you suggest? I used this $.ajax call basically from tutorials online on how to send variable values from a text box to a php file. The variable in here is a query (that is written on the text box) and is sent to mahsql.php and executed. Again, this works just fine if it weren't for the damn pop up. I get my query results in a neat table. Is there another method for this?

Comment: That is too broad. It is obviously not working fine because we don't know what is going on. For example, did you know you were running Webpack? that changes things.

Comment: All I've included are what you see here. Just two files. It works fine as in I see the results, the correct results based on whatever query is written on the textbox "sampleInput". Instead of the $.ajax method like you said, do you know another way I can try to do what I am looking for? To send a value from a textbox to a php file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127491/discussion-between-aluan-haddad-and-orangelime).